# WP8 C# - How can I get the right localized String from the .resx file?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm localizing the app I've built, and I have a problem here.

I added all the strings I use in my xaml in the AppResources.resx file, and I have replaced all the hard-coded strings in the xaml with a binding to the right strings in the .resx file, like this:

```
Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.StringName, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

The problem is that I need to localize a couple of App Bar buttons and a few Messabe Box, so I need a way to get those strings via C#.

I read a couple of tutorials and I came up with this, as for the localized App Bar button:

```
ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("AppResources", typeof(CreditiInfo).Assembly);
ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/back.png", UriKind.Relative));
appBarButton.Text = rm.GetString("BackAppBar");
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);
```

I get a System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException when I try to assign to the AppBar button Text the String I retrieve from the GetString method.
What am I missing?

Also, I read that when you check a new language in the WMAppManifest.xml file, Visual Studio should automatically copy the actual AppResources.resx file and rename the copy with the new current culture selected, but when I try to add a new language it doesn't work.
Do I have to copy and rename the file on my own? Will it recognize the new file when running on a phone that is set on that language?

Thank you for your help!

Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the auto generated `AppResources` class

`string resourceValue = AppResources.NameOfYourLocalizedResource;`

Comment: Ok, thanks :) But if I have two .resx files, a default one in my language and another one in English, for example, so one named AppResources.resx and the other one AppResources.en-US.resx, how can I make the app get the strings from the right file depending on the phone language?
Will this be automatic if I use that code line you wrote?
EDIT: I didn't understand how to use that line, would you mind writing an example for the code I posted in my question? Thanks! :D

Comment: Ok, I figured that out, I forgot to include the namespace declaration so I wasn't able to use that class ahahah
I used appBarButton.Text = MyAppName.Resources.AppResources.NameofTheResource and now it works, thanks! :D

Comment: Yeah, the strings are loaded automatically, from the correct .resx file based on the phones language.